# Change label text on click?

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, label, accordion

So I have a very simple accordion that uses CSS only, I want to change the text Click for details to close and then back again when it's clicked again, anyone have any idea how I would do this? It'd be great if it didn't use JS but I'll take either! Thanks!

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-accordion" /><label for="checkbox" style="text-align:right;">Click for details</label>


.accordion {
    font-size:14px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:790px;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(148,148,148,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(148,148,148,1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(148,148,148,1);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.accordion ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
.accordion li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.accordion [type=radio], .accordion [type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
.accordion label {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:none;
    color:#464646;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-weight:700;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.accordion ul li label:hover, .accordion [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .accordion [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {

}
.accordion .content {
    padding:0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.accordion p {
    color:#333;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}


/* Vertical */
.vertical ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 1px;
}
.vertical ul li label {
    padding:10px;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    border-bottom:0;
}
.vertical ul li .content {
    height:0px;
    border-top:0;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content, .vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    height:220px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the :after pseudo-element with content, something like this:

```
input#checkbox-1:checked + label {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

input#checkbox-1:checked + label:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "Close";
}
```

This doesn't work with IE though without the extra markup. You'll need to put a  element inside the label and hide it with CSS

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-accordion" />
<label for="checkbox" style="text-align:right;"><span>Click for details</span></label>

input#checkbox-2:checked + label span {
    display: none;
}

input#checkbox-2:checked + label:after {
    content: "Close";
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/r292puep/3/ for a demo

Answer (score 0):

Just use a couple of spans inside the label and show them or not based on whether the checkbox is checked

```css
#checkbox-1:checked + label > .on{
    display: inline;
}

#checkbox-1:checked + label > .off,
#checkbox-1 + label > .on {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-accordion" />
<label for="checkbox" style="text-align:right;"><span class="on">I'm ON</span><span class="off">I'm OFF</span></label>
```